# Trouble creating database using the DBCA in Oracle Database 12CR1 on Virtual Box

Tags: database, macos, oracle, virtualbox, oracle12c

I get the following pop up message when I open the dbca (database config. assist.) from the command line:

**dbca cannot create a database as there are no templates under “/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/assistants/dbca/templates/“.**

The "Create Database" message is grayed out, but I can still click 'Next'.

When I go to the next screen, I enter my information and get the following pop up:

**[INS-08107] Failed while processing user inputs at state 'selectModePage'.**

I cannot find any information online.  The VM is setup on my OSX and the only information I can find out there is for Windows.  Please assist.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

just create the /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/assistants/dbca/templates folder and choose to create a template there.